# How get filelist in "npm run <script>" and pipe it to another script?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

In my package.json, I'm running a node module that can only handle one file at a time (I didn't write it). For example:

```
cleancss somefile.css -o somefile-min.css
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
printfilelist -dir /public/css -files *.css | cleancss {filepath}.{fileext} -o {filename}-min.css
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't know of anything ATM, I've thought of writing something like this, but never did. Personally, I would build a small Node.js script that uses the tools JS API, and add an npm script `node .scripts/cleancss.js`.

Comment: @RyanZim what's the tools jsapi? do you have a link?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-api?

Comment: Should be easy to do with Unix tools (particularly [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)), although they may not be available on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar requirement to run `cleancss` across multiple files. Eventually opted for a solution similar to the one discussed in the comments, i.e. using the [clean-css-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-api) with a utility `node.js`.

#### npm-script

```json
"scripts": {
    "cleancss": "glob \"public/css/**/*.css\" | node .scripts/cleancss.js"
},
```

*Note the initial use of [cli-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-glob) (added to `package.json`) for obtaining the paths before piping them to `cleancss.js`.*

#### cleancss.js

The utitlity node script was as follows (albeit rather rudimentary!):

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var readline = require('readline');
var CleanCSS = require('clean-css');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: null,
    terminal: false
});

var options = {
    // ... https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css#constructor-options
    // ... https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css#formatting-options
};

function saveFile(outputPath, minified) {
    fs.writeFile(outputPath, minified, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

function pathParts(srcPath) {
    var ext = path.extname(srcPath),
        name = path.basename(srcPath, ext),
        dirPath = path.dirname(srcPath),
        pathParts = dirPath.split(path.sep),
        pathNoRoot;

    pathParts.shift();
    pathNoRoot = pathParts.join(path.sep);

    return {
        ext: ext,
        name: name,
        pathNoRoot: pathNoRoot
    };
}

function minify(srcPath, outputPath) {
    var output = new CleanCSS(options).minify([srcPath]);
    saveFile(outputPath, output.styles);
}

function processPath(srcPath) {
    var outDir = process.env.npm_package_config_css_outdir || path.dirname(srcPath),
        p = pathParts(srcPath),
        newName = p.name + '.min' + p.ext,
        mkDirPath,
        outputPath;

    if (process.env.npm_package_config_css_outdir) {
        mkDirPath = outDir + path.sep + p.pathNoRoot + path.sep;
        mkdirp(mkDirPath, function() {
            outputPath = mkDirPath + newName;
            minify(srcPath, outputPath);
        });
    } else {
        outputPath = outDir + path.sep + newName;
        minify(srcPath, outputPath);
    }
}

rl.on('line', function(srcPath) {
    processPath(srcPath);
});
```

#### Additional info

1. By default the `.min.css` files are output to the same path as the `.css` source file.
2. However, if you need to change the output destination then you can utilize the [config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#configuration) object in `package.json`. The following example will output all `.css.min` to the `./dist/` path:

```js
"config": {
    "css_outdir": "./dist"
},
"scripts": {
    "cleancss": "glob \"public/css/**/*.css\" | node .scripts/cleancss.js"
},
```

3. `cleancss.js` utilizes [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) to replicate/mirror the `.css` source paths/subfolders in the destination folder when using `config.css_outdir`.